# SQL: Making pairs and count samples

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table (example):

```
ID |LOCATION|DAY           
1  | 1      |20190301   
1  | 2      |20190301  
1  | 3      |20190301  
1  | 1      |20190302   
1  | 4      |20190302  
1  | 4      |20190305     
1  | 5      |20190302   
2  | 4      |20190301       
2  | 1      |20190301   
2  | 3      |20190303   
2  | 2      |20190305
```

where ID is car number, Location is location id, and time is YYYYMMDD. I would like to write a SQL query to count the number for ''pair-wise locations'' for each carID in each month(YYYYMM): how many times the car existed in location i and j. That is, the final results should look like

```
ID|LOCATION 1|LOCATION 2|MONTH |count1|count 2  
1 | 1        |2         |201903| 2    | 1  
1 | 1        |3         |201903| 2    | 1  
1 | 1        |4         |201903| 2    | 2  
1 | 1        |5         |201903| 2    | 1   
1 | 2        |3         |201903| 1    | 1  
1 | 2        |4         |201903| 1    | 2
```

where count1 is the count for location 1 and count2 is the count for location 2, and we construct this for every pair of location1 and location2.

To construct the pairs, I tried:

```
Select n1.location, n2.location
From
(
  Select location
  from table
) n1,
(
  Select location
  from table
) n2
Where n1.location < n2.location
Order by n1.location, n2.location
```

but I would like to count the number for each location (count1, count2) instead of count for pairs.

Can I do this in sub-query in SQL? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: What about the pairs (2, 5), (3, 5) and (4, 5)? Why aren't they included in your expected results

Comment: @GMB using v5.7

Comment: @forpas I omitted them since it becomes longer. Also location pairs (2,5), (3,4), (3,5),(4,5) should be included.

Comment: @Kehoe: you should be able to adapt Gordon Linoff's answer to MySQL 5.7 by moving the `WITH` clause to the `FROM` clause (you will need to repeat the expression twice). This looks like the correct solution to me.

Comment: @GMB Thanks. I applied it. Yet, when I use ''with'' in the first line, MySQL (updated to ver.8) indicates error that ''With is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: EOF, BEGIN,...''. Could you tell me what this error implies?

Answer (score 2):

This is an odd request.  You are looking for independent counts of the two locations, but aligned in one row (it is odd because there is lots of repeated data).

You can do this by aggregated *before* joining:

```
with l as (
      select l.id, l.location, date_format(l.time, '%Y%m') as yyyymm,
             count(*) as cnt
      from carlocations l
      group by l.id, l.location, date_format(l.time, '%Y%m') 
     )
select l1.id, l1.location as location1, l2.location2, l1.yyyymm, l1.cnt as cnt2, l2.cnt as cnt2
from l l1 join
     l l2
     on l1.id = l2.id and l1.yyyymm = l2.yyyymm and 
        l1.location < l2.location;
```

The `with` is supported in MySQL 8+.  In earlier versions, you would need to repeat the subquery in the `from` clause.

EDIT:

Without CTEs, this looks like:

```
select l1.id, l1.location as location1, l2.location2, l1.yyyymm, l1.cnt as cnt2, l2.cnt as cnt2
from (select l.id, l.location, date_format(l.time, '%Y%m') as yyyymm,
             count(*) as cnt
      from carlocations l
      group by l.id, l.location, date_format(l.time, '%Y%m') 
     ) l1 join
     (select l.id, l.location, date_format(l.time, '%Y%m') as yyyymm,
             count(*) as cnt
      from carlocations l
      group by l.id, l.location, date_format(l.time, '%Y%m') 
     ) l2
     on l1.id = l2.id and l1.yyyymm = l2.yyyymm and 
        l1.location < l2.location;
```

Comment: Thanks. I applied your suggestion. Yet, when I use ''with'' in the first line, MySQL (updated to ver.8) indicates error that ''With is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: EOF, BEGIN,...''. Could you tell me what this error implies?  My current code is like this: With S as (Select .... ) Select(...count(DISTINCT id) from (Select ... from S S1 join S S2...)as tpair group by ...

Comment: You need to use subqueries then.  You are not using Mysql 8+.

Comment: Thanks, can we use WITH in subqueries like this (finally, I count the number of unique car ids)? : SELECT time location1 location2 cnt1 cnt2 count(DISTINCT car_id) FROM(  WITH S as( SELECT ... group by ...) SELECT S1.car_id, S1.time, S1.location1, S2.location2 S1.cnt1, S2.cnt2 FROM  S S1 JOIN S S2 ON ...) GROUP BY time, location1,location2,cnt1, cnt2